# Is there a way to read all the files under a parquet partition onto a single spark partition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partitioning, parquet

The data is stored in parquet format. The parquet files are partitioned based off a partition key column (hash value of the user id column)

```
userData/
    partitionKey=1/
        part-00044-cf737804-90ea-4c37-94f8-9aa016f6953a.c000.snappy.parquet
        part-00044-cf737804-90ea-4c37-94f8-9aa016f6953b.c000.snappy.parquet
    partitionKey=2/
        part-00059-cf737804-90ea-4c37-94f8-9aa016f6953a.c000.snappy.parquet
    partitionKey=3/
        part-00002-cf737804-90ea-4c37-94f8-9aa016f6953a.c000.snappy.parquet
```

Given the partitioning scheme, we know:

1. All data for a given user would fall under the same partition
2. A partition can have more than 1 user's data

While reading in the data, I want all the data of 1 user to fall into the same spark partition. A single spark partition can have more than 1 users, but it should have all the rows for all those users.

Currently, what I use is:
SparkSession.read.parquet("../userData").repartition(200, col("UserId"))

(also tried partitionBy with custom partitioner; The sequence of operations: DataFrame -> RDD -> KeyedRDD -> partitionBy -> RDD -> DataFrame; Before the partitionBy, there is a deserialize to object step that explodes the shuffle write)

Is there a way to avoid the repartition and leverage the input folder structure to place a user's data on a single partition?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question seems to be "can i avoid repartitioning by getting spark to repartition the data "...? You can't achieve what you want on data read. If you want the data to be partioned in a certain way as you read it, it has to be partioned that way on disk

Comment: can a partition contain more than 1 row per user?

Answer (score 0):

`SparkSession.read.parquet` should automatically infer partitioning information based on your file paths. You can find more information [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery)

If your file paths are:

```
userData/
    UserId=1/
        part-00044-cf737804-90ea-4c37-94f8-9aa016f6953a.c000.snappy.parquet
        part-00044-cf737804-90ea-4c37-94f8-9aa016f6953b.c000.snappy.parquet
    UserId=2/
        part-00059-cf737804-90ea-4c37-94f8-9aa016f6953a.c000.snappy.parquet
    UserId=3/
        part-00002-cf737804-90ea-4c37-94f8-9aa016f6953a.c000.snappy.parquet
```

When you invoke `SparkSession.read.parquet("/path/to/userData")`, it will partition by `UserId`.

Comment: When I read in the parquet into a dataframe, `df.rdd.getNumPartitions` return 4 (number of physical ***.parquet) not 3 (number of users) which is what I'm hoping to achieve

Comment: That is because you have more than 3 cores on your machine and each row can be processed by an individual core. If you had 3 cores on your machine, then contents of both files with `UserId=1` would go in same partition using Partition Discovery.